# Docker Swarm - is it possible to set up a stack with scalable PGSQL Primary-Replica cluster that's loadbalanced with pgpool or similar solution

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-swarm

I'm working on a task that involves deploying a scalable and load balanced pgsql solution in a docker swarm environment. The idea is to be able to control it via docker swarm replicas settings. I'm trying to find out if the stated requirements are even possible to deploy:

1. A pgpool connection pooling service that would pool all pgsql instances, and would include new replicas of primary-pgsql database automatically
2. A primary-pgsql database service that would act as the initial primary DB
3. A flexible amount of replica-pgsql services that would get replicated from primary-pgsql. The amount of replicas would be controled by the compose file or the replica dashboard changes.

I've tried setting up a sample like such myself, but had little success, this is what I have so far:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  ## PGSQL
  pgsql-primary:
    image: crunchydata/crunchy-postgres:centos8-13.6-4.7.5
    environment:
      MODE: postgres
      PGHOST: /tmp
      MAX_CONNECTIONS: 10
      MAX_WAL_SENDERS: 5
      PG_MODE: primary
      PG_PRIMARY_PORT: 5432
      PG_DATABASE: database
      PG_USER: user
      PG_PASSWORD: password
      PG_PRIMARY_USER: replication
      PG_PRIMARY_PASSWORD: password
      PG_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    volumes:
    - volume-pgsql-primary:/pgdata
    networks:
    - network-stack
        
  pgsql-replica:
    image: crunchydata/crunchy-postgres:centos8-13.6-4.7.5
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    environment:
      PGHOST: /tmp
      MAX_CONNECTIONS: 10
      MAX_WAL_SENDERS: 5
      MODE: postgres
      PG_MODE: replica
      PG_DATABASE: database
      PG_PRIMARY_HOST: pgsql-primary
      PG_PRIMARY_PORT: 5432
      PG_USER: user
      PG_PASSWORD: password
      PG_PRIMARY_USER: replication
      PG_PRIMARY_PASSWORD: password
      PG_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
    - volume-pgsql-replica:/pgdata
    networks:
    - network-stack
    depends_on:
      - pgsql-primary

  pgsql-pgpool:
    image: crunchydata/crunchy-pgpool:centos8-13.6-4.7.5
    environment:
      PG_PRIMARY_SERVICE_NAME: pgsql-primary
      PG_REPLICA_SERVICE_NAME: pgsql-replica
      PG_USERNAME: user
      PG_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - network-stack
    depends_on:
      - pgsql-primary
      - pgsql-replica

## CONFIGS / SECRETS / VOLUMES / NETWORKS
volumes:
  volume-pgsql-primary:
    name: web_vast-db-primary
  volume-pgsql-replica:
    name: web_vast-db-replica

networks:
  network-stack:
    driver: overlay
    name: web-local
```

Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible? And if so what would be decent sources to get myself going? Any bits of advice or even tips would be appreciated.